# How to make a number returned from a function be used for defining no of elements in an array?

Tags: c++, opencv, constants

I am using Opencv/c++.
I get the number of frames in a video using the function
`int noOfFrames = cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT );`

I have also declared an array `int Entropy[noOfFrames];`. But as the variable `noOfFrames` is non-const, it gives an error.

I even used `const_cast` for this but still it gives an error. I want the length of the array to be equal to the no of frames of the video.

How can I do it ???

Comment: It has to be a compile-time constant to be used for a built-in array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, you cannot do that because the size of a c-style array should be a compile-time constant<sup>1</sup>.

Anyway, you have a superior alternative : use `std::vector`

```
std::vector<int> Entropy(noOfFrames);
```

---

<sup>Even if you have compile-time constant, I would not suggest you to use `int arr[size]` which is c-style array. Instead I would suggest you to use `std::array<int,size> arr;` which is again far superior solution.</sup>

Comment: may be you should mention that std::array is a c++ 11 feature.

Comment: @vivek: C++11 is a Standard now, and most compilers support that class already. Also, I will mention C++03 when needed, i.e  C++11 should be assumed by default, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @Nawaz Is any visual c++ compiler supporting c++11 or are there only gcc compilers for this ???

Comment: @apanimesh061: MSVC10 supports many C++11 features. Just check it out.

Comment: @apanimesh061: By the way, you can still use `std::vector` (which is what you need) even if your compiler doens't support C++11.

Comment: I am using that only because `std::array` is not supported by MSVC++10.... ! Thanks!

Comment: @apanimesh061: Please understand that `std::array` and `std::vector` are two different things. Use the first when you know the size at compile-time and when it need not grow at runtime; and use `std::vector` when the size is not known and it may grow at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

You can't declare a static array with a dynamic size. You need a dynamic array:

```
int* Entropy = new Entropy[noOfFrames];

// use here, same as array

delete[] Entropy;
```

But using a vector is just easier:

```
std::vector<int> Entropy(noOfFrames);

// use here, same as array and more

// no need to clean up, std::vector<int> cleans itself up
```